# Using the transpose function across workbooks error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that copies and pastes data from a number of workbooks into one consolidated workbook. The macro was working for a long time but has since begun crashing excel. I would like to try replacing the copy and paste with something like RangeB = RangeA. I am getting the following error:

> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

The last line in the last block of code is throwing the error. Any help is appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub File_Loop_Example()
'Excel VBA code to loop through files in a user selectable folder with Excel VBA


Dim TargetFolder As String, TargetFile As String
Dim wsConsol As Worksheet
Dim CopyLastRow As Long, DestLastRow As Long
Dim TranRange As Variant

'Sets the name of the wsConsol file, if required
Set wsConsol = Workbooks("Consolidation File.xlsm").Worksheets("Raw Data")

'Opens a file dialog box for user to select a folder
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
   .Show
   TargetFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
   Err.Clear
End With

'stops screen updating, calculations, events, and status bar updates to help code run faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'This section will loop through and open each file in the folder you selected
'and then close that file before opening the next file

TargetFile = Dir(TargetFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)

Do While TargetFile <> ""
    DoEvents
    On Error GoTo 0
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=TargetFolder & "\" & TargetFile, UpdateLinks:=False

    TranRange = Workbooks(TargetFile).Worksheets("Summary").Range("F17:F22").Value
    TranRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TranRange)
    wsConsol.Range("L" & DestLastRow & ":Q" & DestLastRow).Value = TranRange
```

Comment: Why are you transposing a row and then pasting it to another row?

Comment: Thanks for the comment that was an error and has been updated!

Answer (score 3):

Change

```vb
wsConsol.Range("C & DestLastRow : K & DestLastRow").Value = TranRange
```

to

```vb
wsConsol.Range("C" & DestLastRow & ":K" & DestLastRow).Value = TranRange
```